# Spyder throwing an error when calling methods from another package/module with the correct number of arguments

Tags: python, spyder

Currently every time I try to run this:

```
       start_1 = Random.randint(0, 25)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

But the definition, and the code completion suggests only two arguments. And yes I am importing Random.

As requested the entire code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 19 22:01:54 2017

@author: 
"""
from random import Random

Random.randint(0, 25)
```

Comment: When trying this on my own computer I have no issues, could you post more details/code to further diagnose the issue?

Comment: Show show full code and full error traceback or otherwise we will remain in the dark.

Comment: I have supplied the entire code.

Comment: just say `import random` and then continue like this `random.randint(0, 25)`

Answer (score 3):

`Random` with capital `R` is the *class* - so you need *instantiate* it:

```
from random import Random           # Random with capital R is the class
random = Random()                   # Instantiate this class
random.randint(0, 25)               # Calling a method of the *object*
```

Of course, the last 2 lines you may substitute with

```
Random().randint(0, 25)             # creating object of class Random just for this purpose
```

Why `...missing positional argument: 'b'` in your (incorrect) use?

The function `randint()` is defined in the class `Random` by the standard way as

```
def randint(self, a, b):
```

so it needs `3` arguments - and you provided only `2`.

(The argument `self` is a special (hidden) argument - in the case of the correct use it will be automatically substituted by the calling *object* itself).

More comfortable possibilities are

```
import random
random.randint(0, 25)
```

or

```
from random import randint
randint(0, 25)
```

as `randint` is in the `random` *module* (cleverly, for our convenience) defined as

```
randint = Random().randint          # Create temporary object and get its method
```

Comment: OK that makes sense. I'm pretty new to python (obviously ;) ). I'd assumed that all methods of a class were static in python - spyder was giving me code completions on "Random." offering the methods. When I've used OOP implementations before it has been in C# and C++ so it is a lot easier to work with - the IDE typically makes it clear what is available as a static method.

Answer (score 2):

you should import only `random`

```
import random

print(random.randint(1,20))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to have worked. I don't understand why second offering of Random is available. When I looked at the source code the method took the two arguments (and of course the self argument). It should have worked fine should it not.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the entire program and if not can you give us the entire program? Also, try doing:
        start_1 = random.randint(randint(0, 25))

Comment: Thanks see amendment.

Comment: also if that doesn't work then I think you have imported it wrong. From what I remember I think it's from random import randint.